# Advice on Boolean Application with Follow-On UV Mapping

Tags: uv, modifiers

## Introduction

I have a ring upon which I would like to carve (etch) lines in, as if it was a metal ring and I etched some lines in it.  I started by generating the primary ring and then used a series of torus's to make an object, let's call that the template, that I could subtract from the primary ring to represent my cuts.

## Problem

When I subtract the template from the primary ring (using the Carve algorithm via the built-in boolean modifier), I get cuts like I wanted with two exceptions:

1. There are no continuous loop cuts around the ring anymore that I can use to aid me in selecting the faces necessary for my UV mapping.
2. A small portion of the template somehow survived.

In the end I want to be able to select all of the outward faces which cover the majority of the ring latitudes (want to avoid the edges).  This was trivial before the boolean was applied because there were well defined and well-behaved edge loops built in and I could use the great blender selection tools to get the desired faces.  After the boolean cut, there are no edge loops which go around the object to help me select all the outward facing edges (including the faces inside the cuts).

## Question

1. How can I fix the geometry to make it easier to select all of the faces that I want?
2. Why did the boolean cut leave part of the cutting template in just one spot?

## Attempts Prior to Asking Question

Before I posted this question, I did try a few things which ultimately did not fix the issue.  One of the most promising attempts was to use the knife projection in ortho mode from the back view using a rectangle which covered the latitudes of the ring I was interested in.  Unfortunately, this resulted in new edges which did not connect at the edge of the cuts (which put me back at square 1).  Is this a bug in the knife projection tool?  Seems to me that the technique should have worked and the projected edges should be connected all of the way around.

## Follow-up Images

### Primary Ring With Template Visible

[image]

### Primary Ring Post Boolean

[image]

### Close-up of Loop Cut Edges Not Lining Up

[image]

### Close-up of Unwanted Remaining Template

[image]

## Blend File

[image]

## System Configuration

Hardware : Macbook Pro (Mid 2013)

Blender Version : 2.79 (sub 0), branch: master, commit date: 2017-09-11 10:43, hash: 5bd8ac9, type: Release

OSX Version : 10.13.1

Comment: This has been [asked multiple times before](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=Booleans&tab=votes), search this site. Just don't use Booleans at all, it will only lead to issues down the road. Use [proper topology](http://topologyguides.com) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.  I have been working to get a similar effect using just mesh tools alone.